# Unable to print expected name using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to print names along with their prefix, but for a given name it is not working as expected as shown below.

Python version 3.7.7

```
string4 = 'Mr. Venkat Mr Raj Mr.RK Mr T Mrs Venkat **Mrs. Raj** Ms Githa Ms. Seetha'
re.findall('[Mm][r-sR-S].?\s?[a-zA-Z]*\w', string4)
```

Output:

```
['Mr. Venkat',
 'Mr Raj',
 'Mr.RK',
 'Mr T',
 'Mrs Venkat',
 'Mrs',
 'Ms Githa',
 'Ms. Seetha']
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the pattern `\bMr?s?\.?\s*\w+\b` here:

```py
string4 = 'Mr. Venkat Mr Raj Mr.RK Mr T Mrs Venkat Mrs. Raj Ms Githa Ms. Seetha'
names = re.findall(r'\bMr?s?\.?\s*\w+\b', string4)
print(names)
```

This prints:

```
['Mr. Venkat', 'Mr Raj', 'Mr.RK', 'Mr T', 'Mrs Venkat', 'Mrs. Raj', 'Ms Githa', 'Ms. Seetha']
```

The reason your current pattern

```regex
[Mm][r-sR-S].?\s?[a-zA-Z]*\w
```

does not match `Mrs. Raj` is that the above can only match `M` followed by `r`, but `s` is not in your pattern.  The character class `[r-sR-S]` can only match *one* letter, not two.

Answer (score 0):

```
r'\b[Mm][rR]?[sS]?\.?\s*\w+\b'
```

Bonus: This one works also with Miss

```
r'\b[Mm][rR]?[iI]?[sS]{0,2}\.?\s*\w+\b'
```

```py
import re
string4 = 'Mr. Venkat Mr Raj Mr.RK Mr T Mrs Venkat Mrs. Raj Ms Githa Ms. Seetha Miss. A'

names = re.findall(r'\b[Mm][rR]?[iI]?[sS]{0,2}\.?\s*\w+\b', string4)
print(names)
```

Result

```
['Mr. Venkat', 'Mr Raj', 'Mr.RK', 'Mr T', 'Mrs Venkat', 'Mrs. Raj', 'Ms Githa', 'Ms. Seetha', 'Miss. A']
```

**Update**: based on the comment of @tripleee. To avoid false-positive like `M. Name`, or `Mris` with my bonus solution, we should list all possible cases

```
r'\b(?:Mr|Mrs|Ms|Miss)\.?\s*\w+\b'
```

This is for me is easier to read than previous regexes but we have to add more case if the upper/lower case is not determined.

Comment: This is somewhat prone to falso positives for arbitrary input; for example, it will also extract plain _M_ and _MRIs._

Comment: That's right. It's better to go with (Mr|Mrs|Miss). But python returns the value in `()` first. Do you know how to make it return the whole matched text instead of value inside `()`? I can get a pair by `((Mr|...)...)`

Comment: If I can guess what you are asking, you can use non-grouping parentheses `(?:...)`